# How do I return variables in my Class with __str__ while not messing with the printed class?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class Amazon:
def __init__(self):
    self.bestsellers = []
def read_books_csv(self, path):
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
        spam = csv.reader(csvfile)
        iterator = iter(spam)
        next(iterator)
        for x in spam:
            if x[6] == 'Fiction':
                print(x)
                self.bestsellers.append(FictionBook(*x[0:7]))
class FictionBook(Book):
def __init__(self, title, author, rating, reviews, price, year, genre):
    super().__init__(title, author, rating, reviews, price, year, genre)
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title} : {self.genre} {self.year[0]}"
```

In my class FictionBook my **str** method returns 3 variables that have to stay that way when printed. However, I also have to created a bestseller list(bestsellers) in my 'Amazon' class with FictionBook objects inside that list. These objects need every attribute of FictionBook (title, author, rating, reviews, price, year, genre)

Now I only add title, genre and year to my bestseller list.

How do I go around this? My **str** in FictionBook can not change according to the assignment I have to do.

Comment: "Now I only add title, genre and year to my bestseller list." - what? No. You're adding the book. The fact that the book only reports certain values in its `__str__` doesn't mean that those are the only values you add to your list.

Comment: Yoy don't return variables, you return *objects*. In this case, your `__str__` method (correctly) returns a `str` object. But that has nothing to do with your list of bestsellers, which contain `FictionBook` objects, not the `str` objects 
 There is **nothing to get around**.

Comment: I add Objects to my bestseller list yes, but these objects only take the title, genre and year inside the list when I print my objects. I need each object to contain all the attributes, like author. How do I do this?